# Comparing WebSQL-Date and Javascript-Date

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

I use Javascript and WebSQL. I have a table in which the creation date of an entry is entered. Now I want to output all entrys, that were made at the same day. For this task I have to make a query in which I can compare Javascript-Date with the dates in WebSQL, that were made by the SQL-Function DATE(). But it seems very difficult, i tried something like this, but it doesnt work:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM easyPicture WHERE creation_date > ?', [myDate], function (tx, results) {
```

myDate here is an Object of the javascript datatype Date.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have same date format for creation_date and date object you are passing from javascript.

Use the below query, it will give you the desired results

```
cur = new Date(); // current date
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM easyPicture WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'creation_date') > ?', (cur.getFullYear()+'-'+(cur.getMonth()+1)+'-'+cur.getDate()), function (tx, results) {});
```